# Is composition with Funcs preferable to inheritance to change behaviour in a single function?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, ironpython, composition

I am working on creating an IronPython console similar to the IronPythonConsole project provided with the [IronPython source code](https://github.com/IronLanguages/). However, I want to make the `ConsoleHost` more extensible than the sample provided, such that it could be extended to run an IronPython interpreter in XNA, or WPF etc. As such, I have created a class `IronPythonConsoleHost` that extends `ConsoleHost` (from `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Shell`), modelled on the [`PythonConsoleHost`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPythonConsole/Console.cs) source.

```
public class IronPythonConsoleHost : ConsoleHost
{
    ...
    public override IConsole CreateConsole(ScriptEngine engine, CommandLine commandLine, ConsoleOptions options)
    {
        return new IronPythonConsole();
    }
    ...
}

// run in a ConsoleApplication
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new IronPythonConsoleHost().Run(args);
}
```

This creates a situation where `IronPythonConsoleHost` can be extended in other applications. For instance, a console could be integrated into XNA as follows (assuming appropriate supporting classes):

```
public class XnaConsoleHost : IronPythonConsoleHost
{
    public override IConsole CreateConsole(ScriptEngine engine, CommandLine commandLine, ConsoleOptions options)
    {
        return new XnaConsole();
    }
}
```

However, this creates a situation where I am inheriting `IronPythonConsoleHost` simply to override a single method - no other functionality of the class needs to be changed. Furthermore, `XnaConsoleHost` is not being used in any situation that expects an `IronPythonConsoleHost` (or indeed a `ConsoleHost`), and this would seem to go against the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), as there is no usage scenario where substitutability is required or appropriate.

It seems it would be more appropriate to design `IronPythonConsoleHost` such that it can be provided with a means of selecting what `IConsole` to create (i.e. using composition instead of inheritance):

```
public class IronPythonConsoleHost : ConsoleHost
{
    public IronPythonConsoleHost(Func<ScriptEngine, CommandLine, ConsoleOptions, IConsole> consoleSelector)
    {
        _consoleSelector = consoleSelector;
    }
    ...
    public override IConsole CreateConsole(ScriptEngine engine, CommandLine commandLine, ConsoleOptions options)
    {
        return _consoleSelector(engine, commandLine, options);
    }
    ...
}
```

This would allow the XNA game to simply construct an `IronPythonConsoleHost` with the appropriate selector function:

```
_console = new IronPythonConsoleHost((eng, cl, co) => new XnaConsole());
```

This approach works, but passing `Func`s seems somewhat clunky. This definitely seems like a situation where inheritance is a much less robust solution, but I don't think composition via awkward `Func`s is necessarily better (especially if selectors are required for other areas - as they probably will be).

**Is composition a good approach for this situation, and if so, are `Func`s appropriate? Or is there a common design pattern that is used in similar situations that I am perhaps missing?**

Comment: don't you just need a factory class?

Comment: Your two examples don't actually *use* the script engine, command line or options - is that common? Or was it just for simplification?

Comment: @JonSkeet the base ConsoleHost class provides those parameters but my IConsole implementation is currently very basic and doesn't use any. Even the default implementation doesn't require all of them: https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Hosting/Shell/ConsoleHost.cs#L137

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a `Func` as a factory method seems reasonable to me - but you may want to overload your constructor to accept a simpler form:

```
public class IronPythonConsoleHost : ConsoleHost
{
    // Full version
    public IronPythonConsoleHost(
       Func<ScriptEngine, CommandLine, ConsoleOptions, IConsole> consoleSelector)
    {
        _consoleSelector = consoleSelector;
    }

    public IronPythonConsoleHost(Func<IConsole> consoleSelector)
        this((engine, commandLine, options) => consoleSelector())
    {
    }

    ...
    public override IConsole CreateConsole(ScriptEngine engine,
        CommandLine commandLine, ConsoleOptions options)
    {
        return _consoleSelector(engine, commandLine, options);
    }
    ...
}
```

So you could then write:

```
_console = new IronPythonConsoleHost(() => new XnaConsole());
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Would you recommend the same approach if there were multiple selectors required? Or perhaps expose them as properties and use object initialisation?

Comment: @jeffora: I think I'd have to look at the specific use case, to be honest. It's hard to generalize usefully :(